# pooling over imputation with LASSO in R

Tags: survey, lasso, data-imputation, glmnet, mice

I've been trying to find an answer to my question, with no success. It could be I'm just not looking for it in the right way (I'm also learning about imputation and lasso as part of the process). So I apologise in advance!

I would like to use imputation, then run lasso regression over different imputations, and then pool over those outputs in R. I can get MICE imputation to work on my data, and LASSO (with glmnet) as well. I can also run a linear regression (using 'lm') on different imputations and then pool over the output.

```
tempData <- mice(data,m=5)
summary(pool(with(tempData,lm(trail~ age+education+stage))))
```

But I haven't been able to run lasso on all imputed data and then pool the results over the different imputations. So I'm wondering whether this is possible at all or I'm just committing an error in my reasoning (or my searching).

Comment: See this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028622/generating-matrices-on-imputed-data-for-use-with-elastic-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028622/generating-matrices-on-imputed-data-for-use-with-elastic-net) It is a R package that gives `glmnet` a formula feature.